# Trying to separate my back-end codes in my front-end(Wordpress)

Tags: html, wordpress, frontend, backend

I created a form that would send the data to an email address and I'm trying to figure out on how to separate my back-end from my front-end in Wordpress. They said i should use `get_template_part()`. Do I code this inside my `functions.php` or is this a separate file?

Answer (score 0):

This should answer that: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_template_part

> Load a template part into a template (other than header, sidebar,
>   footer). Makes it easy for a theme to reuse sections of code and an
>   easy way for child themes to replace sections of their parent theme.
>
> Includes the named template part for a theme or if a name is specified
>   then a specialized part will be included. If the theme contains no
>   {slug}.php file then no template will be included.
>
> For the parameter, if the file is called "{slug}-{name}.php".